# JSON document was not fully consumed

Tags: xml, android-studio, retrofit

ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

```
    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {


        String religion = adapter.retrieveName(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        deleteData(viewHolder, religion);


    }
};




public void deleteData(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final String religion) {
    Call<StatusResponse> call = apiClientInterface.getReligionDeleteStatus(religion);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<StatusResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<StatusResponse> call, Response<StatusResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    List<Religion> myList = new ArrayList<>(religionList);
                    myList.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                    adapter.deleteData(myList, holder.getAdapterPosition());
                    Toast.makeText(ReligionActivity.this, "Delete Religion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ReligionActivity.this, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }



        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<StatusResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(ReligionActivity.this, "Error : " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```